# show/hide button javascript by status

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have code like this

```js
<script>
var a="<?php echo $data[0]->status;?>";
if(a=1){
        $('#cell1').find("a").hide();
    }
 else if(a=2)
 {
  $('#cell1').find("a").show();
 }

</script>
```

```html
<table id="cell1" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th> NO </th>
<th> Name</th> 
<th> Status </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody >
<?php $no=1; ?>
<?php foreach($data as $row):?>
<tr>
   <td> <?php echo $no++;?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $row->name;?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $row->status;?></td>
<td><a href='' type="button"  class="btn btn-circle blue btn-sm">View 1</a>
<a href='' type="button" name="view2" class="btn btn-circle blue btn-sm">View 2</a></td> 
</tr>
</tbody>
  <?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```

when status=1,button view 2 is hidden and vice versa.i have tried but actually all button hidden.
how to resolve it?

Comment: `if(a=1){` => `if(a=1){` in your code you are assigning to comparing also `else if(a=2)` => `else if(a==2)`

Comment: you are not comparing instead you are assigning. Try to use it as a==1 and a===2

Comment: Also, if that javascript is *above* the html in your file, you are calling it *before the elements exist on the page* and youll need to move it below the html of put it inside a DOM ready function

Comment: i have tried,but why all button hidden,my hope only one button can hide/show

Comment: $('#cell1').find("a").hide(); is finding <a> tag instead of var a?

Comment: thanks for all,solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please update your code a little bit to

```
if(Number(a) === 1) {
  $('#cell1').find("a").hide();
}
else if(Number(a) === 2) {
  $('#cell1').find("a").show();
}
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: number is not defined,

Comment: please use Number(), not number()

Comment: other problem i can't hide one button,actually all button hide/show

Comment: hi, if you need to manipulate specific element, please add id to it

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you use `=` instead of `==`.

The difference is that the single equals sign `=` *sets a variable to a specific value* while the double equals sign `==` *compares the two variables* which you have placed beside it.